# How to reflect changes in a spreadsheet through a Java web application without restarting the application?

Tags: java, tomcat, spreadsheet

I am designing a Java web application that uses Tomcat container. I have some data in a spreadsheet that must be available to the web application always. I want to edit the spreadsheet whenever possible and the application must reflect the changes without any restart. What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: If you are simply looking for an option that will make it easy to use an excel spreadsheet in a java web application, I recommend taking a look at Apache POI - HSSF (http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html).

Comment: @misterscruffles:Thanks for your suggestion. I am using Simple ODF API and it seems to be nice. However, I feel my question is somewhat outside such APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Cache the parsing result in your app with a timestamp. Every time your app receives a request, compare that with the last change date of your spreadsheet file. If the cache is older than the spreadsheet, re-parse it and update the cache, if not, use the cached version.

If you need more comprehensive caching, check out [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/)

Unless you need fancy design in the spreadsheet, I would reccommend CSV as the format of your spreadsheet. It is hassle-free to parse and edit, even with a notepad when a more advanced app is unavailable.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion! I thought of this (caching) but was not sure how to go ahead. I will explore the link provided by you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Each time you get a request to your site, open and parse the spreadsheet (you can probably use Apache POI for that).